# Python Pluginsystem

Tags: python, plugins

I am building a custom speech recognition and for that I defined a Command interface. The idea is that the speech recognition returns a String and I got a list of all supported commands. Then I would be going through the list and find the best matching one and execute it.

In order to keep the code maintainable I want to create a plugin system, where you define a class derived from ICommand in a separate file. The folder structure would be the following:

```
project/
├── ICommand
├── commands/
│   ├── command1.py (inherits ICommand)
│   ├── command2.py (inherits ICommand)
```

I am facing multiple problems with that:

1. How can I import ICommand for inheritance in the command1.py file?
2. How do I create one instance of every class contained in a .py file in the commands folder?
3. Is there any way to ensure that the plugin file only contains a definition for a derived ICommand class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- How can I import ICommand for inheritance in the command1.py file?

Your project would have to be inside a proper package. If you are not doing that already, you should. 
Once Python understands that "command1" is inside a package, inside it you can do:

```
from ..ICommand import ICommand
```

(ICommand must be a .py file defining your ICommand, of course).

- How do I create one instance of every class contained in a .py file
  in the commands folder?

For Python, unless you explicitly import a file, a .py file is as good as any data file sitting on the directory. The language allows you to, but does not perform any "auto-discovery" of whatever files you will have under your plug-ins.

You can do that yourself, our you can use a framework that does this kind of thing - `zope.configuration` is one, but you have to create xml-like files with the folders it should scan.

Doing it yourself can be easy, it is just a matter of listing the desired folders, and call `__import__` for any Python files in there. 
TThe object returned by the call to `__import__` is the module itself, you can then just check its contents for subclasses (or otherwise implementations of) `ICommand` and instantiate then.

```
module = __import__(...)
plugins = {}
for name, obj in module.__dict__.items():
    if isinstance(obj, ICommand):
         plugins[name] = obj()   # This instatiate the class
```

I have two answers with explicit examples of how to do that:

[Load module to invoke its decorators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47334197/load-module-to-invoke-its-decorators/47337069#47337069)

[Python: import every module from a folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043485/python-import-every-module-from-a-folder/10044530#10044530)

- Is there any way to ensure that the plugin file only contains a
  definition for a derived ICommand class?

Yes.

But you should not put that restriction there, as you state it. 
The snippet above for getting the ICommand subclasses inspect all of a modues top level contents, and you could easily raise an exception on any variable, function or class there that is not an ICommand subclass.
That however is not a rational restriction: it is usual in Python to need small "utility" functions that are not class related, or other variables that will hold constant values - it is not usefull to constrain those to be class members for your plug-in.  Likewise, if you are worried about the plugins containing arbitrary code that should not be there: you can't prevent that at all. It is not feasible to securely "sandbox" a Python file in a Python process. Very good people tried for years to have a "Python sandbox", only to be frustrated. (If that is a requirement, use O.S. level process resource restrictions, and run your plug-ins i.e. only import their files, in a process with those restrictions)

Otherwise, you may be meaning that you want "a single subclass of ICommand per file", with no other restrictions: then just insert a check in the above loop to instantiate the plug-in - if it finds a second class in the same file, raise an exception.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am going to try that.